# MudBlazor MudDataGrid virtualized ServerData

Tags: datagrid, mudblazor, data-virtualization

I have read a very [nice and detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77008207/use-mudblazor-muddatagrid-serverdata-to-load-paged-data-from-an-api) from James McCormack but he did not cover virtualization. How can MudDataGrid be used with server side data not with pagination but virtualization.
I would like to ask for some help in this problem, please.